# Why can't you use auto as a template type argument (e.g. std::array<auto, 5>)?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Why is this not allowed, for example:

```
std::array<auto, 5> myArray {

};
```

It would make my life so much easier, as I would be allowed to store multiple data-types inside the array. I'm sure there's a logical explanation, just wondered what it was.

Comment: "as I would be allowed to store multiple data-types" No, it would not. `auto` is not dynamic typing.

Comment: `auto` does not allow different types.

Comment: This, right here, is why `auto` was a bad idea. I predicted this misconception four years ago.

Comment: Try doing `auto var = 5;` and then assigning a class/struct like `std::complex` to it. You should quickly see that no, you can't store multiple types in `var`.

Comment: I -1'd for a moment, because the misconception is quite sad. But I removed the downvote because than in itself is (a) not your fault, and (b) not a reason to consider this as a bad question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I think this misconception is pretty minor, as it's only had by people first learning C++ (or about `auto`), and is quickly explained away. Thus, I'm not sure this is a *major* con for `auto`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit hardly a difficult prediction: the same thing happened with C# about five years ago.

Comment: We need `dynamic` in C++ :)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Spoilsport.

Comment: @Cornstalks: There are certainly worse ones.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yet I'm not sure this misconception is really a big problem. That's one of the very few instances of it I've ever seen of it. A prediction that happens once every four years (exaggerating!) is not a bad one, but also not one that's gonna change the world. Of course people not understanding the very basics of C++'s type system will probably fall for that *once*, but well, then that's probably not their worst problem anyway. I agree that *Herb Sutter*'s approach of *"almost always auto"* is a bit extreme, yet I don't want to miss `auto` either.

Comment: @ChristianRau: I did not say "once every four years". I said "four years ago", and I was not exaggerating.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, *I* was exaggerating, since I knew that you *didn't* say *"once every four years"*, *I* said it, and it was an *exaggeration on my side*, since I guess it happens more often than *"once every four years"*. I never doubted that you made this prediction *"four years ago"* and weren't exaggerating with that. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`auto` is used to deduce *one* type from an expression. Using your suggested syntax would not help because exactly one type can be stored in a container. If you need a way to store any type in the container, take a look at `boost::any`, so you can use

```
std::array<boost::any, 5> myArray;
```

Comment: So... by your explanation we can expect the new question: _"Why doesn't `std::array<auto, 5> arr { 1,2,3,4,5 };` work, while `auto arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };` works as expected?

Comment: In `auto arr[]={1,2,3,4,5};`, `auto` will deduce the type, which is a C style array. You cannot use `auto` as a template parameter because the compiler cannot deduce the type, even if every element is the same so there is only one type.

Comment: @cdmh: You didn't really explain it. You just repeated the assertion as its own explanation.

Comment: @sehe `{ 1,2,3,4,5 }` is not an expression, so it has no type to deduce. You could ask the language "find me a type `T` such that `std::array<T, 5> arr { 1,2,3,4,5 }` is valid", but it is impractical to invert `template` type substitution: doing so in the general case can require solving the halting problem, which is impossible. For that to work, one would need a weaker `template` metaprogramming language, or some syntax or conventions to tell the language the "right" way to turn constructor arguments into a type: the second is actually being worked on for future C++ standardization I believe.

Comment: @Yakk aww, you really didn't have to explain. I was using the Socratic method to point out sloppiness in the explanation. (And, seeing how well it works, I might ask you: If `{ 1,2,3,4,5 }` is not an expression, then surely `std::vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4,5 };` must involve _aggregate initialization_, don't you agree :/ - I kid, only half though...)

Comment: @Yakk Thanks for your thoughtful angles. Yeah, C++ will probably get some more type magic in the near future. That said, `std::array<auto, 5> arr { 1,2,3,4,5 };` would just work in, say, Haskell; there is no real reason it couldn't be made practical. As such, the answer should _really_ have explained in terms of language rules (_deducible context_)

Comment: @sehe `foo<T> x = { 1, 3, 4 }`, where `foo<T>` has a constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list<U>`, where `U` is an arbitrary turing-complete computation from the type `T`.  How do you determine, in this general case, which `T` is the one wanted?  C++ doesn't require that the mapping `foo<T>`->types of constructors of `foo<T>` be invertible, let along requires that such an inverse be described and practical.  Possibly Haskell does, which makes this problem much, much easier, and equivalent to the signature matching problem with `template` functions in C++.

Comment: @Yakk yeah, you reframed my Socratic q. to fit the OP's. However, I had no such intention. My point was merely `std::initializer_list<T>` _is an expression_, AFAICT :/ _(I thought my "I kid" and other not-so-subtle hints would have been enough to warn you not to take it seriously. Sorry if I bothered you.)_

Comment: this might be sloppy... @sehe sure but taking Socrates at face value is about the only way to tolerate that old sod.  As for the expression bit: {} could be an initializer list or uniform initialization.  We cannot tell until we know what is on the lhs of the `=`: so it is not an expression, just part of one.

Comment: @Yakk Point conceded. Well done :/ (also, _lol_ at "old sod")

Answer (score 9):

`auto` is not some sort of magical flexible data type that can store any type of data. `auto` is a mere compiler keyword that tells the compiler that it has to deduce the specific type automatically. The type is deducted at compile time, meaning that `auto` is implicitly replaced with a specific type. *One* specific type. There's no way `auto` would somehow help you to store different types of data in the same array.

And in order for the actual type to be deducible, the compiler must have enough information to deduce it. In your example the relationship between the `auto` and the data that must be used to perform deduction (the initializers in the `{}` list) is not known to the compiler, which is why `auto` does not work in this context.

For example (borrowing the example from the comments), when you write something like this

```
auto a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

the entire declaration is built entirely from core language constructs. The compiler immediately knows that the values in `{}` are initializers for array elements, whose type is described by keyword `auto`. So, the meaning of `auto` is easy to define using the core language concepts.

But in a declaration like

```
std::array<auto, 5> myArray  = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

the template `std::array` is seen by the compiler proper as a user-defined data type. The relationship between the values in `{}` and template arguments is also user-defined and hidden inside the implementation of `std::array`. It can be arbitrarily complex. It is not even known whether such relationship exists. And this is why it generally not possible to derive the actual type of `auto` is such cases.

Answer (score 7):

> Why is this not allowed

To allow that, you'd need a way for a template to specify how to infer template parameters from an object's initialiser. That would be quite a large and complicated change to the language, for little benefit.

> It would make my life so much easier, as I would be allowed to store multiple data-types inside the array.

No, it wouldn't. An array can only contain a single type; all this would allow you to do is deduce that type from the initialisers (if they all had the same type), which is of limited use.

In general, `auto` represents a static type, inferred from the type of an expression. It sounds like you want either:

- an ordered collection of objects of different static types. This is available in the C++11 standard library as `std::tuple`; or
- an array of dynamically typed objects. There is no such thing (as yet) in the language or standard library; but [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/any.html) or [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant.html) will give you such a thing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that there is `boost::any` etc.. However, they would not allow me to do: `cout << foo[0];` and would have to re-cast each of the elements?

Comment: @Phorce: `any` will need casting; `variant` or `tuple` elements can be streamed directly. If you need convenient dynamic types, then you may not have chosen the best language.