# Can 'auto' be used as a subtype of lambda argument in C++?

Tags: c++, lambda

C++ code with `auto` as a part of lambda argument type is accepted by GCC, e.g.:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto make_vector = []( std::initializer_list<auto> v ) 
        { return std::vector<typename decltype(v)::value_type>{v}; };
    auto v = make_vector( {1,2} );
    std::cout << v[0] << ' ' << v[1] << '\n';
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/z43bEjMc9

Here the argument type is `std::initializer_list<auto>` and it is really convenient sometimes. But other compilers complain:

> A template-argument cannot be a type that contains 'auto'

Is it a GCC-only extension of the language or a new C++ feature that will appear in other compilers as well? If the first is the case then how can it be turned off to maximize language conformance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like it's a [bug in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97479). Altough it says it's solved in the version of GCC you're using...

You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701279/why-cant-you-use-auto-as-a-template-type-argument-e-g-stdarrayauto-5) more on why you can't use `auto` in this context.

It was correctly pointed out to me that this case is for a function parameter. It's still not allowed in C++20, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60358154/auto-as-a-template-argument-placeholder-for-a-function-parameter).

Comment: A variable declaration of the form `A<auto> a` is not allowed in recent versions of gcc. A function parameter is different.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Good point, but I've looked it up, and it's still related though. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I looked it up too and it looks like it is a bug after all.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I can't seem to find if there's a bug report for GCC. Have you found one by any chance?

Comment: No, it is the same bug, it should be re-opened. It is not allowed in C++-20. It was allowed in Concepts-TS.

Comment: Scratch that, I have no idea whether it's valid in C++20.

Comment: I reported GCC bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=101498

Answer (score 5):

This is not the valid way to declare *generic lambdas*. [[dcl.spec.auto.general]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.spec.auto.general#2):

> A *placeholder-type-specifier* of the form *type-constraint<sub>opt</sub>*
> `auto` can be used as a *decl-specifier* of the *decl-specifier-seq* of a *parameter-declaration* of a function declaration or *lambda-expression* and, if it is not the `auto` *type-specifier* introducing a *trailing-return-type* (see below), is a *generic parameter type placeholder* of the function declaration or *lambda-expression*.

Note that `std::initializer_list<auto>` is not in the form of *type-constraint<sub>opt</sub>* `auto`.

Since C++20 you can delcare *template parameter list* for [generic lambdas](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.lambda.general#5). E.g.

```
auto make_vector = []<typename T>( std::initializer_list<T> v ) 
    { return std::vector<typename decltype(v)::value_type>{v}; };
```